# given area of a triangle, minimum value of its perimeter stack exchange

Tags: optimization, triangles, maxima-minima

given area of traingle $\sqrt3 $ , find minimum value of it's perimeter.

I didn't get any idea where to start,

Comment: Useful: [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). Expresses the area in terms of side lengths.

Comment: i tried it, differeniate wrt to s and equate it to 0, i got polynomial cubic eq.

Answer (score 1):

We know with Heron's formula (let $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$, half of the perimeter):

$$\sqrt3=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

And so

$$3=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\tag{$*$}$$

With AM-GM, we see

\begin{align}
\frac13s&=\frac{(s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)}3\\
&\geq \sqrt[3]{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
\end{align}

And so

$$\frac{1}{27}s^3\geq(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$$

which becomes, when multiplying both sides by $s$:

$$\frac{1}{27}s^4\geq s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)=3$$

simplify this to see

$$s^4\geq 81=3^4$$

Which we can take the fourth root of to get $s\geq 3$. Equality in AM-GM holds iff all the terms are equal, so $s-a=s-b=s-c$ which happens iff $a=b=c$, thus, $a=b=c=2$ (to satisfy equation $(*)$). The minimum perimiter is $6$ (since $s\geq3$, and $s$ is half the perimeter) and being reached by an equilateral triangle with side lengths $2$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for that. $$\frac13s=\frac{(s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)}3$$is just algebra on the definition of $s$ not AM-GM, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You're simply using that $2s=a+b+c$ so that $$(s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)=3s-(a+b+c)=3s-2s=s$$